# Compilation error: X11/Shell.h: No such file or directory under Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.0 (Plow)

Tags: c, redhat

When compiling a library,I got this error:

```
/home/alex/Downloads/OCCT/src/IVtkDraw/IVtkDraw_Interactor.hxx:28:10: fatal error: X11/Shell.h: No such file or directory
   28 | #include <X11/Shell.h>
```

and under this machine,/usr/include/X11 exists,and contains files like this:

```
ap_keysym.h   extensions  keysymdef.h  Xarch.h  Xcursor       Xfuncproto.h  XlibConf.h  Xlocale.h  Xos_r.h      Xregion.h    Xw32defs.h
cursorfont.h  fonts       keysym.h     Xatom.h  Xdefs.h       Xfuncs.h      Xlib.h      Xmd.h      Xpoll.h      Xresource.h  XWDFile.h
DECkeysym.h   HPkeysym.h  Sunkeysym.h  Xauth.h  XF86keysym.h  X.h           Xlibint.h   Xosdefs.h  Xproto.h     Xthreads.h   Xwindows.h
dri           ImUtil.h    Xalloca.h    Xcms.h   Xft           XKBlib.h      Xlib-xcb.h  Xos.h      Xprotostr.h  Xutil.h      Xwinsock.h
```

As you can see,Shell.h not exist,question is

```
Which lib should I install to ensure Shell.h exist?
```

Comment: Try libXt-devel.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu that file is in package libxt-dev (`apt-file search X11/Shell.h`). According to [this](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=libxt-dev), that package should exist in Fedora as libXt-devel.

Comment: Thanks,I knew how to do under Ubuntu,don't know how to do under Redhat